# Angular2 view not updated after callback function

Tags: javascript, meteor, angular, meteor-slingshot

I'm using Meteor-Angular2 and slingshot package for uploading images to S3 storage. when returning from the function and assign to binded string, view not updated. (setTimout function is working and updating view, but uploader function not)

```js
export class AdminComponent {

   public urlVariable: string = "ynet.co.il";

    constructor() {
        this.uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("myFileUploads");
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.urlVariable = "View is updated";
        }, 10000);
    }

    onFileDrop(file: File): void {
        console.log('Got file2');

        this.uploader.send(file, function (error, downloadUrl) {
            if (error) {
                // Log service detailed response
            }
            else {

                this.urlVariable = "View not updated";

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions (`() =>`) instead of `function ()` to retain the scope of `this.`

```
    this.uploader.send(file, (error, downloadUrl) => {
        if (error) {
            // Log service detailed response
        }
        else {
            // now `this.` points to the current class instance
            this.urlVariable = "View not updated";

        }
    });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: still the view is not updated, unless I move to another route in the router or do something that fire refresh of the page.

Comment: Where is `onFileDrop` being called from?

Comment: thanks !
with your answer and addition to    this._ngZone.run(() => {this.urlVariable = "View not updated"; }); it is working now and updating immediately!
:-)

Answer (score 0):

this one is working for me: (narrow function+Ngzone)

```
 this.uploader.send(file, (error, downloadUrl) => {
        if (error) {
            // Log service detailed response
        }
        else {
            // now `this.` points to the current class instance
            this._ngZone.run(() => {this.urlVariable = "View not updated"; });


        }
    });
```